# Como ignorar comentários em arquivos ppm P3?

Tags: c, processamento-de-imagens, fopen

Na função ler_arquivo_ppm_p3(const char *nome_arquivo) como seria para ignorar comentários (# cometário) em arquivos ppm P3?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PIXEL {
    int r, g, b;
} PIXEL;

typedef struct IMAGEM {
    int largura;
    int altura;
    int maxcor;
    PIXEL *pixels;
} IMAGEM;

IMAGEM *nova_imagem(int largura, int altura, int maxcor) {
    IMAGEM *imagem = (IMAGEM *) malloc(sizeof(IMAGEM));
    imagem->pixels = (PIXEL *) malloc(largura * altura * sizeof(PIXEL));
    imagem->largura = largura;
    imagem->altura = altura;
    imagem->maxcor = maxcor;
    return imagem;
}

void destruir_imagem(IMAGEM *imagem) {
    free(imagem->pixels);
    free(imagem);
}

PIXEL *pixel_da_imagem(IMAGEM *imagem, int x, int y) {
    return &(imagem->pixels[y * imagem->largura + x]);
}

IMAGEM *ler_arquivo_ppm_p3(const char *nome_arquivo) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) return NULL;
    int largura, altura, maxcor, x, y;
    IMAGEM *imagem = NULL;
    char formato[6];
    fgets(formato, 6, arq);
    if (strcmp("P3\n", formato) == 0) {
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &largura);
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &altura);
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &maxcor);
        imagem = nova_imagem(largura, altura, maxcor);
        for (y = 0; y < altura; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < largura; x++) {
                PIXEL *p = pixel_da_imagem(imagem, x, y);
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->r));
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->g));
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->b));
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return imagem;
}

void salvar_arquivo_ppm_p3(const char *nome_arquivo, IMAGEM *imagem) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "w");
    int x, y;
    fprintf(arq, "P3\n%d %d\n%d", imagem->largura, imagem->altura, imagem->maxcor);
    for (y = 0; y < imagem->altura; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < imagem->largura; x++) {
            PIXEL *p = pixel_da_imagem(imagem, x, y);
            fprintf(arq, "\n%d %d %d", p->r, p->g, p->b);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o comentário sempre está no primeiro caracter lido, basta fazer uma comparação simples:

```
fgets(formato, 6, arq);
while ( formato[0] == '#' )  // não esqueça de testar se é final
                             // de arquivo (EOF), também
     fgets(formato, 6, arq);
```

agora se o comentário pode estar em qualquer lugar, você pode usar uma função do tipo [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) para fazer pesquisas com substrings

PS. Estou ignorando a necessidade de se testar se é fim de arquivo. Na prática é necessário este teste